# Pumpkin puree refreeze

Tags: freezing

Can I freeze a cheescake made with pumpkin puree that was previously frozen? I used it in the cheesecake but the event was cancelled to another day. How long will the cheesecake stay fresh without freezing?

Comment: What kind of crust on the cheesecake? That will usually take the first hit.

Comment: Are you asking about freezing the pumpkin, or the cheesecake you made from it?

Comment: Graham cracker crust. Pumpkin purée was frozen. Made cheesecake with the purée and now want to freeze the cheesecake.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Is it that you want to freeze the whole cake but you're not sure if the pumpkin purée can be refrozen? Or rather how long you can keep the cheesecake in the fridge? Or are you thinking about scooping out the pumpkin part and put that in the freezer?

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear what you're asking (based on your comments). If I didn't get it right, feel free to change it back.

Answer (score 2):

The inner part of the cake will be fine in the fridge for about 3 days if covered and uncut. Unfortunately, the crust will start to get soggy after about 24 hours. The cheesecake can be frozen now and will be fine for at least a few weeks, but the crust will be soggy as soon as it's defrosted. I don't know of any way to keep the crust's just baked texture.

Comment: it's a little late for it, but one could bake the cheesecake in a pan on parchment, sans crust and bake a crust separately, then put the cheesecake on the crust as it's served.

Comment: @sourd'oh - Wow! Or you could just eat out :)